# align numbers based on the decimal point with \textbf and stars in the table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I am stuck with the following problem.

I would like to align numbers based on the decimal.

The problem is that I have `\mathbf` statements as well as `$^{***}$` or `$^{**}$` or `$^{*}$` in some of the columns.

Is there a way to align the numbers easily?  I provide an example of the table below.

```
 \setlength\LTleft{0pt}            % default: \parindent

\setlength\LTright{0pt}           % default: \fill

  \begin{center}

  \begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{1}{l}*{12}{c}}

\caption{\textbf{Table}}\\\hline

&\multicolumn{3}{c}{\emph{Panel A }}  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\emph{Panel B }}\\

$Variable_{j,t}  & $\mathbf{2.545}^{***}$ &                        & $0.730$                & $\mathbf{0.553}^{*}$    &                         & $0.409$                 \\

                  & $(0.374)$              &                        & $(1.777)$              & $(0.326)$               &                         & $(1.329)$               \\

$Variable3$       &                        & $\mathbf{1.932}^{***}$ & $1.218$                &                         & $0.156$                 & $-0.249$                \\

                  &                        & $(0.423)$              & $(1.829)$              &                         & $(0.349)$               & $(1.315)$               \\


                  &                        &                        &                        & $(0.126)$               & $(0.122)$               & $(0.123)$               \\

$pvalue$        &   0.032  &     0.6811         &  -  &   0.016     &0.760 &  -        \\
\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{center}
```

Comment: unrelated but never put `longtable` in a `center` environment

Comment: you should make aur effort to help you by providing complete small document with your table, which we can copy and compile ... welcome to tex.se!

Answer (score 4):

[image]

your code has more issue. find them with comparison with the following *mwe*. in it i use `siunitx` package for defining column types, `booktabs` for rules and `etoolbox` for robustness of command for `boldface numbers:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, longtable}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{etoolbox}% <-- new
\newcommand{\B}{\fontseries{b}\selectfont} % renew def. for non-extended bold font
\robustify\B

    \begin{document}
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}            % default: \parindent
\setlength\LTright{0pt}           % default: \fill
  \begin{longtable}{@{}  >{$}l<{$}
                        *{6}{S[input-symbols = {(- )},
                          table-space-text-post={(},
                          table-space-text-post ={***},
                          detect-weight,
                          table-format=1.3]}
                    @{}}
\caption{Table}\\
    \toprule
    &\multicolumn{3}{c}{\emph{Panel A }}    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\emph{Panel B}}        \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-7}
\mathit{Variable}_{j,t} & \B 2.545$^{***}$  &    & 0.730    & \B 0.553$^*$ &   & 0.409  \\
    & (0.374)           &   & (1.777)       &  0.326        &       & (1.329)           \\
\mathit{Variable3}      &   & \B 1.932$^{***}$  & 1.218 &   & 0.156 &  -0.249           \\
    &                   & (0.423)           &  (1.829)  &   & (0.349)   & (1.315)       \\
    &                   &   &               & (0.126)   & (0.122) & (0.123)             \\
\mathit{pvalue}         & 0.032 & 0.6811    &  {--}     &  0.016  &  0.760  &  {--}     \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtable}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

This defines a version of `dcolumns` alignment using `\boldmath` instead of normal math, and defines bold math to use `b` (bold standard width characters) instead of `bx` (bold and wider characters) so that the digits line up;

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{dcolumn}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}{bold}{OT1}{cmr} {b}{n}
\newcolumntype{d}{D..}
\makeatletter
\newcolumntype{b}[1]{>{\boldmath\DC@{.}{.}{#1}}c<{\DC@end}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ld{3.4}}
  aaa &1.2 \\
  aa  & 012.3^{*{*}*} \\
  aa  & 012.3 \\
  x & \multicolumn{1}{b{3.2}}{12.34} \\
 a &  654.78
\end{tabular}
\end{document}


\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{dcolumn}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}{bold}{OT1}{cmr} {b}{n}
\newcolumntype{d}{D..}
\makeatletter
\newcolumntype{b}[1]{>{\boldmath\DC@{.}{.}{#1}}c<{\DC@end}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ld{3.4}}
  aaa &1.2 \\
  aa  & 012.3^{*{*}*} \\
  aa  & 012.3 \\
  x & \multicolumn{1}{b{3.4}}{12.34} \\
 a &  654.78
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```