# Fixed column width and align on decimal with siunitx

Tags: siunitx

I have the following Latex table I generated with the `KableExtra` package in `R`. What I want to do now is make all columns the same/fixed width and align on decimals. The second of these is not to be supported by `KableExtra` so I will need to do this in Latex directly. The `siunitx` package seems a good choice for this, but I can't get it to work.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ccccccccc}
        \toprule
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{ } & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Cumulative change} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Marginal change} \\
        \cmidrule(lr){2-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-9}
        ${k}$ & ${(Cons.)}$ & ${Spread_t}$ & ${\overline{R}^2}$ & ${SEE}$ & ${(Cons.)}$ & ${Spread_t}$ & ${\overline{R}^2}$ & ${SEE}$\\
        \midrule
        $1$ & $1.76^{**}$ & $2.09^{**}$ & $0.18$ & $4.05$ & $1.76^{**}$ & $2.09^{**}$ & $0.18$ & $4.05$\\
        & $(0.56)$ & $(0.40)$ &  &  & $(0.56)$ & $(0.40)$ &  & \\
        $2$ & $1.73^{**}$ & $2.06^{**}$ & $0.28$ & $3.02$ & $1.78^{**}$ & $2.06^{**}$ & $0.17$ & $4.06$\\
        & $(0.39)$ & $(0.29)$ &  &  & $(0.52)$ & $(0.39)$ &  & \\
        $8$ & $2.65^{**}$ & $0.96^{**}$ & $0.18$ & $1.70$ & $ 4.21^{**}$ & $-0.59 $ & $0.00$ & $4.45$\\
        & $(0.26)$ & $(0.16)$ &  &  & $(0.64)$ & $(0.53)$ &  & \\
        $12$ & $3.31^{**}$ & $0.35^{*}$ & $0.04$ & $1.39$ & $ 4.52^{**}$ & $-0.93^{**}$ & $0.07$ & $2.66$\\
        & $(0.19)$ & $(0.14)$ &  &  & $(0.32)$ & $(0.30)$ &  & \\
        \bottomrule
        \multicolumn{9}{l}{\textit{Note: }}\\
        \multicolumn{9}{l}{Robust standard errors in parentheses.}\\
        \multicolumn{9}{l}{$^{*}$ $p < 0.05$, $^{**}$ $p < 0.01$ in a two-tailed test.}\\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The fixed column width I tried to achieve with `*{9}{S[table-column-width = 2 cm]`, but this gave me a lot of "! Extra }, or forgotten $." type errors.

For the alignment I tried to make something out of [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/410742/156662) and other answers and the `siunutx` manual, but I got a whole bunch of errors and problems where my significance stars disappeared, etc. I want to center all columns, but aligned on the decimal. The first columns should be aligned on the implicit decimal.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you add an image of what your code currently produces and a visual example of what you want it to look like (use paint on the what it currently produces)

Comment: You might want to have a look at: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/180009/134144

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with use of `S` column type from package `siunitx`:

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)

i would also use `threepartablex` package for simpler writing table notes (`...\tnote{**}` instead of `$...^{**}$`). it also provide command `\note` for `tablenotes` environment:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex} % <--- for \note, \source
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
\begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Table title}
    \label{tab:statistic}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\hskip\tabcolsep\extracolsep{\fill}}
                c *{8}{S[table-format=1.2,
                         input-symbols={( )},
                         table-space-text-post={**}
                        ]}}
        \toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{ }
        & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Cumulative change}
            & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Marginal change}               \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-9}
${k}$   & {(Cons.)} & {Spread$_t$}  & {$\overline{R}^2$}& {SEE}
        & {(Cons.)} & {Spread$_t$}  & {$\overline{R}^2$}& {SEE} \\
    \midrule
1       & 1.76\tnote{**}    & 2.09\tnote{**}    & 0.18  & 4.05
        & 1.76\tnote{**}    & 2.09\tnote{**}    & 0.18  & 4.05  \\
        & (0.56)            & (0.40)            &       &
        & (0.56)            & (0.40)            &       &       \\
2       & 1.73\tnote{**}    & 2.06\tnote{**}    & 0.28  & 3.02
        & 1.78\tnote{**}    & 2.06\tnote{**}    & 0.17  & 4.06  \\
        & (0.39)            & (0.29)            &       &
        & (0.52)            & (0.39)            &       &       \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
    \begin{tablenotes}[para, flushleft]\footnotesize
    \note:   Robust standard errors in parentheses.\\
    \item[*]    $p < 0.05$,
    \item[**]   $p < 0.01$ in a two-tailed test.
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

**edit:**
i miss requirement that all column should have equal width. this can be achieved for example with use of `tabularx` table environment where for column headers is used command `\mcx` defined in preamble as:

```
\newcommand\mcx[2]{\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}{#1}}
```

to my taste this requirement not result in a better looking table:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\newcommand\mcx[1]{\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}{#1}}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex} 
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
    \sisetup{table-format=1.2, input-symbols={( )}}
\begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Table title}
    \label{tab:statistic}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{\hskip\tabcolsep\extracolsep{\fill}}
                 >{\centering\arraybackslash}X 
                    *{2}{S[table-space-text-post={**}]}
                    *{2}{S}
                    *{2}{S[table-space-text-post={**}]}
                    *{2}{S}
                            }
        \toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{ }
        & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Cumulative change}
            & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Marginal change}               \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-9}
${k}$   & \mcx{(Cons.)}         & \mcx{Spread$_t$}  
            & \mcx{$\overline{R}^2$}    & {SEE}
                & \mcx{(Cons.)}             & \mcx{Spread$_t$}  
                    & \mcx{$\overline{R}^2$}    & \mcx{SEE}     \\
    \midrule
1       & 1.76\tnote{**}    & 2.09\tnote{**}    & 0.18  & 4.05
        & 1.76\tnote{**}    & 2.09\tnote{**}    & 0.18  & 4.05  \\
        & (0.56)            & (0.40)            &       &
        & (0.56)            & (0.40)            &       &       \\
2       & 1.73\tnote{**}    & 2.06\tnote{**}    & 0.28  & 3.02
        & 1.78\tnote{**}    & 2.06\tnote{**}    & 0.17  & 4.06  \\
        & (0.39)            & (0.29)            &       &
        & (0.52)            & (0.39)            &       &       \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \begin{tablenotes}[para, flushleft]\footnotesize
    \note   Robust standard errors in parentheses.\\
    \item[*]    $p < 0.05$,
    \item[**]   $p < 0.01$ in a two-tailed test.
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I managed to set the fixed column with using `table-column-width=1.5cm` in the S column options.

Comment: @Alexander91, very good!